# Classroom grouping in Python

Tags: python

I have a class with 24 students and I want to make 6 groups of 4 students each. These 6 groups will rotate each week. It is important that no group will have 2 same students each week. At some point it will start over of course...

Lets say students are numbered 1 to 24.

Groups 1-2-3-4 first week and 1-2-5-6 next week are not acceptable because they have students 1 and 2 in the same group.

Groups can not have the same person in 2 different groups in a week. Groups 1-2-3-4 and 1-5-6-7 in the same week are not acceptable.

How can I do this in Python please?

I tried itertools but I can not make it work. I get groups like these:

First week: 1-2-3-4
Next week: 1-2-3-5

They have in common students 1-2-3 ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what you mead that These 6 groups will rotate each week ?

Comment: Is it that crucial? Why not just `random.shuffle` and take groups of four?

Comment: Share the code that you've written so far.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To get good answers, please try to solve your problem and come back with a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure some clever person will come along with a list comprehension that will do this in one line, but here's a nested loop that'll do it for you, I think.

```
# get the initial set of groups
groups = list(zip(*[iter(range(1,25)] * 4))

def regroup(groups):
    j = 0
    new_groups = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for group in groups:
        for item in group:
            new_groups[j].append(item)
            j = (j + 1) % 6

    return new_groups
```